# Can I use a string as an index in a QComboBox?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I'm currently calling a stored proc in Oracle to populate a QComboBox in PYQT.  The data appears like this:

code: 'PAY_COMP'
description: 'Payment Company'

code: 'USER_COMP' 
description: 'User Company'

I want to show the description in the combobox but want to use the code as the index, is this possible?  Reason is, when user selects 'Payment Company', I want to send 'PAY_COMP' to the backend to be updated.

Or is there another way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about python, but at least in C++ you can attach `QVariant` data to each element in the combo box. A `QVariant` can be virtually every type, for example a string or an enum.

When populating the combo box I would use the member function `void QComboBox::addItem(const QString & text, const QVariant & userData = QVariant())`. Then when an item is selected by the user and I know the current index of the combo box, I can use `QVariant QComboBox::itemData(int index, int role = Qt::UserRole) const` in order to obtain the `QVariant` of that item, which can then be converted to the actual type the contained data has, for example using `QString QVariant::toString() const`.

The combo box also provides a method for obtaining the index of one particular data item: `int QComboBox::findData(const QVariant & data, int role = Qt::UserRole, Qt::MatchFlags flags = static_cast<Qt::MatchFlags> ( Qt::MatchExactly | Qt::MatchCaseSensitive )) const`

Now you'll only have to transfer that to python, but I assume the interface will be the same.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response, with your help I was able to get this working.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, not sure if I set this up correctly, when inside comboChanged, getting some odd results:

#Weight
for index in range(rowCount):
 combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboChanged)
        for t in comboBoxWeight:
         combo.addItem(t[0], QVariant(t[1]))
        self.tableWidgetCode.setCellWidget(index,0,combo)

Comment: Ok, had one more question. Now that I was able to set up the comboboxes with a 'code' and 'description', once I get the data back from the procedure, I need to set the data in the appropriate row. 

So if I get the data 'PAY_COMP' returned from the proc, how do I go about setting it in the table within the combobox to display 'Payment Company'? 
I'm assuming I need to use something like: 

self.tableWidgetCode.cellWidget(0,0).setItemData(row) but I can't get it working... @user

Comment: I'm actually not exactly sure what you are trying to do. If changing the selected item of the combobox to a particular item is what you want to do, you can use `QComboBox::findData` to obtain the index of the corresponding item (as aforementioned). Then you can use `QComboBox::setCurrentIndex` to set this item to be the selected one. So for example: `comboBox->setCurrentIndex(comboBox->findData(PAY_COMP))`.

Comment: Yes, this got it working correctly now with your help, thank you.  Only issue now is when the comboChanged() function is called, I need to get the currentRow and if user keeps selecting the combo boxes in the tbale, currentRow() never changes.  I have to click on another column to get it to change.  Googled this but came up empty.... @user

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. Which table are we actually talking about? There was no table involved in the question.

Or are you talking of the items in the combobox?

Comment: Created a 5 row table tableWidgetCode, have a combobox in the first column.  When I select row 2 for instance and click on the combo, and I try and use tableWidgetCode.currentrow(), it's not returning the correct row.  @user

Comment: I don't understand what the table has got to do with the combo box. Maybe update the question.

Comment: From what I understand the comboBox is on top of the cell in the table so when I click on the comboBox in row 2, it's not setting the currentRow() in the table correctly.  After more reading, it seems I have to do this programatically, meaning I need to select the row in the code when the user clicks on a comboBox in the table.  Tried moving this discussion to chat but am unable to.  @user